# Using a function in a query that returns a string or a null

Tags: sql-server, join, function

I want to join 2 tables `'addresses'` and `'user_info'` on `user_id` and `app_id` 
(which is a number, or it is null), like these 2 examples:

```
select * from user_info 
left outer join addresses on addresses.user_id = user_info.user_id 
and addresses.app_id is null

select * from user_info 
left outer join addresses on addresses.user_id = user_info.user_id 
and addresses.app_id = 1234
```

What the app_id should be is complicated and I have written a function to return it. It returns a string, which would be for example "is null" or "= 1234".
I'm trying to call it with this syntax:

```
select * from user_info 
left outer join addresses on addresses.user_id = user_info.user_id 
and addresses.app_id dbo.fnGetAppId(addresses.user_id)
```

I get this error:

> Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Line 3 An
>   expression of non-boolean type
>   specified in a context where a
>   condition is expected, near 'dbo'.

I'd like to keep the query very simple as it is without having to determine if the function is returning a null or not.

Can you suggest the best way to keep the calling query very simple?

(I'm in sql server 2005.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NULL != NULL. If either address.app_id = NULL or fnGetAppID = NULL, the comparison will fail.  I would write the comparison as:

`coalesce(address.app_id, 'NULLSTRING') = coalesce(dbo.fnGetAppID(addresses.user_id), 'NULLSTRING')`

Comment: This is starting to look interesting as I begin to understand it.  Thanks.

Comment: All responses were educational, but this is the best.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're just missing an = sign

addresses.app_id dbo.fnGetAppId(addresses.user_id)

rather than

addresses.app_id = dbo.fnGetAppId(addresses.user_id)

Answer (score 0):

So if fnGetAppId is null then this query looks like the following?

```
select * from user_info left outer join addresses on addresses.user_id = user_info.user_id and null
```

I doubt that is what you want. :)

You may want to do a simple check in your logic, before calling the query, to properly handle a null for fnGetAppId and as Clyde mentioned you also need an = sign for a non-null

.

Answer (score 0):

As James Black pointed out, you have AND where you probably want WHERE.  Beyond this, I suggest you make the function a boolean one (passing address.app_id to it as one more argument), so it can perform an IS NULL or = 1234 as appropriate (Bill's COALESCE solution is clever indeed, but putting the appropriate comparison inside the function is more straightforward, IMO).

Comment: Thanks for your response.  But can you answer the question I put in the comments for Luke?